# Jquery character limit with variable input field length

Tags: jquery, character

i am mirroring an input field with another input field.

If you take a look at this  http://jsfiddle.net/bloodygeese/tQm8G/7/

I need to let the user enter as many characters as the display area can take

for example:

the display field showing now will allow say 50 characters because it is 200px wide but the user might click a button that will make it only 100px wide, so then it can only hold 25 characters?

so, the input area will always be same length  but the display area will change size and must be allowed to be filled with characters.

Hope this all makes sense?

Comment: I did not understand the question, however, to increase the size of the area so you can try: var totChar, len, charW; $('#inputarea').bind('keyup keypress blur', function() {$('#displayarea').val($(this).val());charW = $(this).css('font-size').replace('px','');totChar = $(this).val().length +1;len = $(this).width();if(len < (totChar * charW)){$('#displayarea').animate({'width': '+='+charW+'px'},0);}}); It's an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concept was intriguing so I created a plugin function that determines the maximum letters. The plugin inserts a test span offscreen and then continually adds the letter "O" until span width exceeds input width. You can pass a css object map in options to help improve testing width. Plugin needs extending a bit to add functionality you want which isn't clear in original post

Since it's not clear how you want this ultimately to work it currently just throws an alert when max is reached

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/tQm8G/10/

```
$.fn.maxLetters = function(options) {
    defaults = {
        testLetter: 'O',//
        widthBuffer: 30,// allows for some padding left/right
        css: null,
        events : 'keyup' // space seperated as in on() API
    }
    var $test_el = $('<div style="position:absolute; left:-999em"><span id="max_letter_test"></span></div>');
    var opts = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    return this.each(function() {
        var $input = $(this);

        $('body').prepend($test_el);
        if( opts.css){
            $test_el.css( opts.css);
        }

        var maxW = $input.width() - opts.widthBuffer;
        currW = 0, test_text = '', $test = $('#max_letter_test'), maxLetters = 0;

        while (currW < maxW) {
            test_text += opts.testLetter;
            $test.text(test_text);
            currW = $test.width();
            maxLetters++;
        }
        $test_el.remove();
        $input.data('max_letters', maxLetters).on(opts.events, function() {
            var max = $(this).data('max_letters')
            if ($(this).val().length >= max) {
                alert('Max letters(' + max + ') reached')
            }
        });

    });
}
```

Example useage:

```
$('#inputarea').maxLetters({css:{fontSize: '20px'}});
$('#inputarea2').maxLetters({css:{fontSize: '20px'}, widthBuffer:0});
```

Comment: I don't know how you understood my question as I re read it this morning and it confused me! but your solution is absolutely perfect and just what I needed!!! thanks you.. Is there any way that instead of an alert I could just display the "maximum character reached" within the form and it also stop the ability to type?

Comment: I added the text after input of how many allowed. I don't have time today to do much else with this. Issues get trickier with events like paste and I'm really not exactly sure what you want to do when limit reached  http://jsfiddle.net/tQm8G/13/